# C# convert dictionary into CSV like string

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` I want order it alphabetically by the keys and convert it into a string that can be written into a CSV file with the keys as column headers and the values as values for that column.

My onordered dictionary looks like:

```
{
"Name" : ["John", "Ciara", "Moses"],
"Age" : ["23", "16", "37"],
"State" : ["Alabama", "Florida", "New York"]
}
```

The end result will look like:

```
Age,Name,State
23,John,Alabama
16,Ciara,Florida
37,Moses,New York
```

Please how I can achieve this in C#?

For clarity, here is a [link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57f7f71a7b992e699400013f/csharp) to what the task entail.

And below is my approach of solving it. I converted the string into a dictionary with the column headings as keys. My problem now is converting the dictionary back to the string format.

```
public static string SortCsvColumns( string csv_data )
  {
    var data = csv_data.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var values = data.Skip(1).ToArray();
    var splittedValues = new List<List<string>>();
    
    var dataSet = data[0].Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToDictionary(x => x, x => new List<string>());
    
    for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) 
    {
      splittedValues.Add(values[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList());
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < splittedValues.Count(); i++) {
      var splittedValue = splittedValues[i];
      for(int j = 0; j < splittedValue.Count(); j++) {
        dataSet.Values.ElementAt(i).Add(splittedValue[j]);
      }
    }
    dataSet = dataSet.OrderBy(key => key.Key);
    
  }
```

Can someone suggest the best approach to do this please.

Comment: [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Is json a requirement here? If not, its usually a good idea to show actual test code to set up test data, not unrelated data structures

Comment: What's unordered about the dictionary? The keys (which we know are unordered as it's a dictionary) or the values?

Comment: @00110001 Actually the task is to sort a csv string. I can't seem to edit my question. What I did was to convert the table string into a dictionary and then ordered it. Now I'm looking for the best way I can convert it back to the table string.

Comment: @Enigmativity the keys. But my concern now is converting the dictionary into a string as formatted in my question

Comment: What does the dictionary have to do with all of this? it would be easier to sort this before its converted to a cev format. if that is the case this would be fairly trivial

Comment: @00110001 Actually my code doesn't take care of that. It retrieves the csv data from somewhere else, my task is to sort and return the string

Comment: Create a class, use [csv helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to parse it, sort using linq

Comment: I thought you were starting with a dictionary. Why are you parsing CSV?

Comment: If you want them sorted by keys, why not use `SortedDictionary`?

Comment: You want someone to solve this for you? What is the point then?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a map to re-order the columns in sorted order by column header:

```
var map = new StringReader(csv_data).ReadLine() // get header line
                                    .Split(';') // split into array of headers
                                    .Select((h, n) => new { header = h, OrigPos = n }) // remember original position
                                    .OrderBy(hn => hn.header, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) // sort into new position
                                    .Select(hn => hn.OrigPos) // return just old position new new order
                                    .ToList();
```

Then remap each CSV line into the new order and recombine into a `string`:

```
using var sr = new StringReader(csv_data);
var ans = String.Join("\n",
                      sr.ReadLines()
                        .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
                        .Select(columns => String.Join(";", map.Select(pos => columns[pos]))));
```

This requires an extension method on `TextReader` to enumerate the lines of a `TextReader`:

```
public static class StringReaderExt {
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(this TextReader sr) {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            yield return line;
    }
}
```